# How does DataGridViewCell.Datagridview property get set?

Tags: .net, oop, collections, datagridview

The `DatagridviewCell.Datagridview` property is read-only.  Same applies for other datagridview elements with a `Datagridview` reference, like rows and columns.  Yet somehow when you add/remove elements from a datagridview, this property is set properly behind the scenes, so there is never any inconsistency between the parent datagridview's references to its elements, and vice versa.

How is datagridview accomplishing this?  I'm trying to do something similar myself.  The only "trick" that I know of is to put the collection definition inside the class definition or vice versa, so that the element or collection has access to other's private fields, but looking at the datagridview namespaces this does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateGridView is using the "internal" access modifier.  As you may know, there are 4 different access modifiers.

```
public    string MyPetPeeve
private   string MyPetPeeve
protected string MyPetPeeve
internal  string MyPetPeeve
```

Here's a quick summary of the behaviour of the access modifiers:

public:   MyPetPeeve is accesible to anyone who wants to know.

private:  MyPetPeeve is only accessible from within the class or struct that contains it.

protected: MyPetPeeve is accessible to the class or struct that contains it. PLUS, any class derived from MyPetPeeves containing class.

internal:  MyPetPeeve is accessible to any class or struct that exists in the same assembly. For example, the DataGridView exists in the System.Windows.Forms assembly, so any class or struct found in System.Windows.Forms can change DatagridviewCell.Datagridview property.  To anyone else outside System.Windows.Forms, in this case: you, it appears to be private.

Comment: That sounds logical, though a little odd.  Since it's necessary that the parent dgv and child element references to each other remain synchronized, allowing _anything_ inside Forms assembly to change an element's dgv property is a pretty broad scope.  I guess it's alright since MS obviously has control of the entire assembly, but I wonder if additional checks are in place.

Comment: It's not really odd, it just places the burden of syncronization on the developer in exchange for some WONDERFUL un-restricted access that outside developers cannot even see.  By the way if you are defining a property like this:  public string Text { get; set; }, you can make the "set" to internal like this: public string Text {get; internal set;}.  If you would like to go "under the hood" and see the code that Microsoft has written for the DataGridView, you can use Reflector, by Red-Gate. www.reflector.net

Comment: As long as the developer (and future developers) remember the rules for synching.  But perhaps the best solution, as mine was a bit convoluted:  an abstract child class defined inside the collection definition, that upon startup passes the collection a delegate reference that allows modification of its private `_parentColl` field.  That way a child's collection reference remains hidden to all, except for the one delegate inside the collection, which it uses to synch when adding/removing children.  Overly complicated probably.